# How did Kovacs go from being arrested to in bed with Ortega in episode 5?

Tags: altered-carbon

I was startled  to see Kovacs being led out in handcuffs at 41:20, and then in the next scene in bed with Ortega. How did he get out of jail? What did I miss?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The scene with the arrest doesn't actually have Kovacs in it.  That's Ryker, the guy whose sleeve Kovacs is in.  It's a flashback to the moment he's arrested and ultimately loses his sleeve. The bed scene is back in the present, where Ortega is telling the story from the flashback to Kovacs (who is in Ryker's body/sleeve).